# Return customizer setting value in functions.php

Tags: theme-customizer

This is probably very unusual but I have a need to return a customizer setting value in functions.php to then pass into a function.

At the moment I'm trying this but the variable is empty. The customizer is set up correctly as I can get the value inside the theme files.

```
    $breakpoint = get_theme_mod( 'setting_navigation-breakpoint', '768' );

        function hn_add_inline_css($breakpoint) {
            $custom_css = '
                @media (min-width: ' . $breakpoint . 'px) {
                  .form-inline .form-group {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                  }
                  ...
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: nothing unusual. Can you confirm you haven't saved the customizer before?

Comment: Yeah I've saved it with a different value to the default

Comment: how you saved it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to get the customizer value inside the function, not passing the value to the function.

```
    function hn_add_inline_css() {
        $breakpoint = get_theme_mod( 'setting_navigation-breakpoint', '768' );

        $custom_css = '
            @media (min-width: ' . $breakpoint . 'px) {
              .form-inline .form-group {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                vertical-align: middle;
              }
              ...
```

Comment: So what do you think made the difference?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can pass a variable to a function that you register through an add_action. add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hn_add_inline_css($breakpoint)' ); didn't work.

Comment: Yes, getting to the point `add_action` should set a function name and number of accepted arguments... as most important ,but in there you don't set the parameters. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: please [edit] your question to set the details.